# I want to add multiple rows in one cell of MUI V5 Table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, material-ui, mui-datatable

### Image samples

> The code will show the below image as a result.

[image]

I want it to look like this image just it has to be combined with above image too
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LL31.jpg

### This is my Table data

```
   const columns = [
    { id: 'name', label: 'Name', minWidth: 170 },
    { id: 'email', label: 'Email Address', minWidth: 90 },
    {
      id: 'project',
      label: 'Project',
      minWidth: 170,
      align: 'center',
    },
    {
      id: 'access',
      label: 'Access',
      minWidth: 170,
      align: 'center',
    },
    {
      id: 'action',
      label: 'Action',
      minWidth: 170,
      align: 'center',
    },
  ];

  function createData(name, email, project, access, action) {
    return { name, email, project, access, action };
  }

  const rows = [createData(data.username, data.email, '', '', '')];
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this using MUI `Table`. But MUI `DataGrid` supports grouping. You can check the examples here https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-grouping/

Comment: Okay that was a nice suggestion and thanks for the information!